# ioctl giving Invalid Argument

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

I want to send a opened file descriptor between two different programs. So I am using `ioctl` with `named pipes` to do so. But there I am getting "Invalid argument" error for `ioctl()`.

```
#include <stropts.h>
#include "accesories.c"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define MSGSIZ 63
char *fifo = "fifo";

int send_err(int fd, int errcode, const char *msg)
{
    int     n;

    if ((n = strlen(msg)) > 0)
        if (write(fd, msg, n) != n)    /* send the error message */
            return(-1);

    if (errcode >= 0)
        errcode = -1;   /* must be negative */

    if (send_fd(fd, errcode) < 0)
        return(-1);

    return(0);
}

int send_fd(int fd, int fd_to_send)
{
    char    buf[2];     /* send_fd()/recv_fd() 2-byte protocol */
    
    buf[0] = 0;         /* null byte flag to recv_fd() */
    if (fd_to_send < 0) {
        buf[1] = -fd_to_send;   /* nonzero status means error */
        if (buf[1] == 0)
            buf[1] = 1; /* -256, etc. would screw up protocol */
    } else {
        buf[1] = 0;     /* zero status means OK */
    }
    //printf("From the write %d\n",buf[0]);
    if (write(fd, buf, 2) != 2)
        return(-1);

    if (fd_to_send >= 0)
        if (ioctl(fd, I_SENDFD, fd_to_send) < 0)
        {
            printf("Eroor ::: %s\n",strerror(errno));
            return(-1);
        }
    return(0);
}




int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int fd, j, nwrite;
    char msgbuf[MSGSIZ+1];
    int fd_to_send;


    if((fd_to_send = open("vi",O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        printf("vi open failed");

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: sendmessage msg ... \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* open fifo with O_NONBLOCK set */
    if((fd = open(fifo, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)
        printf("fifo open failed");
    
    /* send messages */
    for (j = 1; j < argc; j++)
    {
        if(strlen(argv[j]) > MSGSIZ)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "message too long %s\n", argv[j]);
            continue;
        }
        strcpy(msgbuf, argv[j]);
        if((nwrite = write(fd, msgbuf, 6)) == -1)
            printf("message write failed");
    }

    printf("From send_fd %d \n",send_fd(fd,fd_to_send));
    
    exit(0);

}
```

The file accessories .h only contain some common include files nothing else.
First I am sending a simple message and then calling `send_fd` which is first sending a 2 byte message and then have to send file descriptor using `ioctl()`. But it is not.

Comment: How are you creating the file descriptor?  I_SENDFD is a STREAMS thing and won't work with any pipe.  It's also a highly obscure API.  It's far (far!) more common to use the `sendmsg()` syscall to send file descriptors over Unix domain sockets instead.  Is there any reason you want to use I_SENDFD?

Comment: I am opening file vi to create the file descriptor. Is it is possible to send file descriptor using send message? I mean opened file descriptor not just the integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [linux doesn't support I_SENDFD](http://fixunix.com/unix/84093-streams-pipes-ioctl-i_sendfd.html). The comments indicate that `I_SENDFD` is in the documentation, but is not actually supported, and results in the error message you encountered. The [wikipedia entry for STREAMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS) states the linux kernel does not have any support for streams. The wikipedia entry does point to a couple of third-party packages that could be used to add streams support, but [LiS](http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/kernel.html) has not been ported to the 2.6 kernel, and [OpenSS7](http://www.openss7.org/index.html) hasn't had any active development in 4 years.

However, linux does support something similar. This mechanism uses a special message type `SCM_RIGHTS` to deliver a file descriptor over a UNIX domain socket with `sendmsg` and obtained from `recvmsg`. Examples can be found with a simple web search, a complete example seems to be from the book *The Linux Programming Interface*, with source for [sending](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/scm_rights_send.c.html) and [receiving](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/scm_rights_recv.c.html).

Comment: I dont want to send file descriptor/socket descriptor using UNIX domain sockets. Is there any way around.

Comment: @knoxxs: I am sympathetic, but it is a little like saying I don't want to use eggs to make an omelet. Instead of sending it to the process, can you use `fork`/`exec` instead?

Comment: Linux supports I_SENDFD, or at least documents support for it.  But it's strange and rare.  Socket-based file descriptor passing is the mechanism that everyone actually uses and tests.

Comment: @AndyRoss: The link I provided explained it was code that was left in that should not have been. My search for other sources support this.

Comment: Please comment on a downvote, so I know what needs to be improved, thanks!

Comment: @knoxxs: Why don't you want to use UNIX domain sockets?

Comment: I want to send fds to two different processes that doesn't have parent-child relation. Why I want anything else only to learn (more). I think there are multiple ways to do something in linux.

Comment: @knoxxs: That is true, but sometimes it means a lot of work. If you really want to use streams, you will have to port (and then support) one of the third-party add-ons to your linux kernel, or write your own.