# why does ioctl I_SENDFD return no permission (EPERM)?

Tags: sockets, tcp, file-descriptor, ioctl

I want to send a file descriptor of a tcp socket from process A to process B, so that process B can create another tcp socket with the same file descriptor.

the idea is exactly the same as [passing file descriptors](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ivana/courses/tos/sistemi_knjige/pomocno/apue/APUE/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html)

the key function call is the following:

```
ioctl(fd, I_SENDFD, fd_to_send);
```

but it always returns EPERM /* Operation not permitted */

I verified the domain socket file descriptor fd is working, as I could send normal messages through that fd.

I don't know what's wrong. I googled, nobody seems to mention I_SENDFD has permission issue. I tried using "sudo" to run my programs. It still doesn't work.

I have also tried allowing everything for that file descriptor`fcntl(fd_to_send, F_SETFL, S_IRWXU|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR|S_IRWXG|   S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IRWXO|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH|S_IXOTH);`

doesn't work either.

how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.
Linux doesn't support this, but still keeps the API, which is evil.

for details regarding this issue, see [ioctl giving Invalid Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355552/ioctl-giving-invalid-argument)

here is a workaround solution: [Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t)

(which I haven't tried)

Comment: Have you tried `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358684/can-i-share-a-file-descriptor-to-another-process-on-linux-or-are-they-local-to-t` ?